# How to know if there is no more pics to disable (nxt/prv) button

Tags: jquery, html, image, jquery-animate

I have this code

css:

```
div#container{
overflow: hidden;
width: 331px;
}

div#content {
position:relative;
}
```

jquery:

```
$("#left").click(function(){
$("#content").animate({"right": "+=328px"}, "slow");
});

$("#right").click(function(){
$("#content").animate({"right": "-=328px"}, "slow");
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="left"><<</button>
<button id="right">>></button>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><img src="images/img1.gif"></td>
<td><img src="images/img2.gif"></td>
<td><img src="images/img3.gif"></td>
<td><img src="images/img4.gif"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description1</td>
<td>Description2</td>
<td>Description3</td>
<td>Description4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

when i click for example prv button 15 times the div move 328px every time!
my question is how to know the last postion that the gallery should stop moving?

thank you

Comment: update:http://jsfiddle.net/9sYWK/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like using tables for that... Divs make your code much more fluid, and would allow an elegant solution: is(':last-child') on active div

But since you're doing it with table, I can think of two ways of doing this

One is using a counter, then checking it against number of columns of table. If displaying more than one column per step, then it will be total number of columns / visible columns:

```
$(function(){
    var position = 1;

    $("#left").click(function(){
    var size =  $("#content table").find('tr').first().find('td').size();

        if(position < (size / 2) ) {
            $("#content").animate({"right": "+=198px"}, "slow");
            position ++;
        }
    });

    $("#right").click(function(){
        if(  position > 1) {
            $("#content").animate({"right": "-=198px"}, "slow");
             position --;
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9sYWK/5/

The other solution consists in calculating how many times #content has moved. You can get it by using `$("#content").css('right');`. Since you know you always move your div in 328px steps, you can divide it by 328 to get how many times it was clicked

Comment: thanks, but "right btn" doesn't work! also you made it "1 column" and i want it "2 column", like my example.

Comment: ok it's work now you didn't change "var count" to "var position", but like i said how can i make "2 column" insted of "1 column" ?

Comment: No problem... Just make size / 2: http://jsfiddle.net/9sYWK/5/ (I've also fixed variable name... Sorry about that)

Comment: ok can you please put your solution as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, you need a counter somehow.

One way would be to count the td's in a row?

```
//Add a class to your td's
<td class="img_gallery"><img src="images/img1.gif"></td>
<td class="img_gallery"><img src="images/img2.gif"></td>
<td class="img_gallery"><img src="images/img3.gif"></td>
<td class="img_gallery"><img src="images/img4.gif"></td>

// in your js ...
$td_count = $(".img_gallery").size();

// Now you have many different ways of dealing with this,
// you can have a counter, or allow to move 5 * 328, whatever you want.
```